# my validation is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm following along with railstutorial.org and I have run into a road block.
Basically, I put together the code for my Micropost model as below:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :content, :length => { :maximum => 140 }
end
```

The problem was when I start the web server, tried to create a new record with content having more than 140 characters in length. It should not allow me to save a new record, but it did.

This looks very straight forward. and what was the possible mistake I could have made?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: perhaps you can show us the code you use to build and save the record. eg `post = MicroPost.new(:content => "a"*150)` then `post.save` should return false if validation fails.

Comment: You should even be able to try this in the console. Create a post with more than 140 chars in the content, and then ask if it is `valid?`. The console is a great tool for debugging your rails app.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now, after rewriting all code starting over again.

This was by using the original code:
validates :content, :length => {:maximum=>140}